# How to correct limit values in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Please help to understand how to correct limit for "team" field by "company" team?

It's my code :

```
class CustomCompany(models.Model):

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,
            default="None",
            unique=True
            )


class CustomTeam(models.Model):

    team_name = models.CharField(
            max_length=30,
            default="None"
            )
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(CustomCompany,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='company_name+',
            to_field='id',
            )


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CustomCompany,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default='None',
            to_field='company_name',
            related_name='company'
            )
    team = models.ForeignKey(CustomTeam,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default=1,
            related_name='team_name+',
            limit_choices_to={"company_name_id":"company_id"},
            )
```

And problem in last string (limit_choices_to)
How to correct do this, limit teams by company?

Current error, if it's required the next :

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'company_id'

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `CustomTeam` already belongs to a `CustomCompany`, have you considered dropping the field `CustomUser.company` and just using `CustomUser.team.company` ?

The models stay almost the same:

```
class CustomCompany(models.Model):
    ...

class CustomTeam(models.Model):
    ...
    company = models.ForeignKey(CustomCompany, ...)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    team = models.ForeignKey(CustomTeam, ...)
```

A few notes:

- a `ForeingKey` should not have a `int` as default value, it has to be a model instance; I would just leave the default out of the model definition.

Comment: Unfortunately still in this case I cannot limit values of team based on company :(